# how to improve spacing using jquery plugin export to pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am importing multiple html tables using jquery plugin using this line of code

```
<a href="#" onclick ="$('#whole').tableExport({type:'pdf',separator: ',', escape:'false', pdfFontSize:8, pdfLeftMargin:35});">As PDF</a>
```

it showing data but column are mingled with each other how can i make proper spacing between columns so that it become readable ? currently there is much text which is cant readable. One column merge with another

Comment: Seeing your HTML, the output you're currently getting and the output you want to have would help a lot here.

Comment: there is normal body element inside of it multiple tables in html